# How can I add a custom CSS class to a main menu button on Astra Theme for Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I need to add a specific CSS class to the main menu button on my Wordpress site. I am using an Astra theme on my website, under Header > Primary Menu > Last Item in Menu - I have elected to use a button. I am using the button as a login button and I am trying to set up dynamic login/logout links using the WPmembers plugin. Fortunately, WPmembers have the functionality to handle the dynamic login/logout links. In order to use it the menu item must have the correct CSS class.

As it stands I cant see an option to edit the default CSS class of the button (Its not under WP-Admin > Appearance > Menus (as it would be if this were a normal menu item).

I have used the developer inspector and the button currently has a CSS class (just not the correct one). Can I change this by adding custom CSS on Wordpress? I have googled it and found a few articles about using JQUERY .addclass("your_custom_class_here") I have no idea what JQUERY is and have tried using the custom CSS editor but it doesn't seem to recognise the .addclass function.

Has anyone got any suggestion? Many thanks, Guy

**The button currently has a class of ast-custom-button 
* I need it to be “wpmem_loginout”

[link to my site here](https://www.cut-work.com)

EDIT:

Thanks Andrey for providing this code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'login_out_button', 10);

function login_out_button() { ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("button.ast-custom-button").addClass("wpmem_loginout");
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

QUESTION:

I have added the code to my-custom-function.php file 
It seems to work but not quite as I intended. 
Using the Inspector I can see that it has added the class "wpmem_loginout" to the end of the existing class "button.ast-custom-button" so I have ended up with class="ast-custom-button wpmem_loginout".

Can anyone suggest an edit to the code that removes the old class?

thanks,
Guy

Comment: I've edited Andrey's answer to include `removeClass()` which you can use to remove the existing class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library and there are various methods to add JavaScript code to WordPress. 
One of them is creating a plugin and adding JavaScript code to it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Extra Code
 * Plugin URI: http://www.myplugin.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: Important codes
 * Version: 1.0
 */
add_action('wp_head', 'login_out_button', 10);

function login_out_button() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".ast-custom-button")
            .addClass("wpmem_loginout")
            .removeClass("ast-custom-button");
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Create a file with `.php` extension and add the code above. Then create `.zip` archive with the `.php` file that you just created and upload it to WordPress the usual way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrey. I have followed your advice and it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am wrong in assuming that I can add the same CSS class to a button and it will work.

Comment: I have followed the guide for a normal menu item and that works just fine. Not really sure why this wouldn't work!

Comment: @GuyBeardsley Good that you solved your problem. I can see an error on your website about jQuery not being defined. I believe this is because the theme loads jQuery **after** the code above, so If you still want the method to work, replace `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` with `jQuery(window).load(function() {`, I think it will fix it. Let me know if it does or does not. However if you don't need it anymore, you can disable/delete the plugin.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for your help. I think it wasn't working because the I didn't provide the correct name for the button. When I added the correct name to the code that you provided the class was added.

Comment: However - The class has been added to the end of the existing class so I have ended up with "ast-custom-button wpmem_loginout" - Is there anything I can add to the code that will remove the first part of the name "ast-custom-button"?

Comment: @GuyBeardsley I see that you made an edit to the post asking how to delete the other class that the button has but look, unfortunately, your question got voted to be closed (not by me), so people can't answer it anymore. I also can't invite you to stackoverflow chat because you have <20 reputation. So you can either create a new question or you can message me on Skype or something.

Comment: @GuyBeardsley add `jQuery(".wpmem_loginout").removeClass("ast-custom-button");` **after** the `jQuery(".ast-custom-button").addClass("wpmem_loginout");` line

Comment: Sweet - This has changed the class to the correct thing! Thanks :)

Comment: @GuyBeardsley Glad it worked! I would appreciate if you accepted my answer (check mark below my answer's score).

Comment: I've added `removeClass()` to the existing code.  No need to do another search for the elements - just chain the add and remove methods and do it all in 1 hit.